# Could not find ButterKnife compiler

Tags: android, gradle, butterknife

I integrated ButterKnife into my project, since then it has been impossible for me to build it

I've tried different versions of the library but nothing seems to work

Here is the error during the build:

```
Could not find com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:7.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/7.0.1/butterknife-compiler-7.0.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/7.0.1/butterknife-compiler-7.0.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/7.0.1/butterknife-compiler-7.0.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/7.0.1/butterknife-compiler-7.0.1.jar
  - https://jitpack.io/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/7.0.1/butterknife-compiler-7.0.1.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/7.0.1/butterknife-compiler-7.0.1.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

And this is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.toto"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //Retrofit Dependencies
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'

    // Butter Knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:7.0.1'

    // ZXing
    implementation 'com.github.tobrun:QR-Vision-Fragment:master-SNAPSHOT'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

I have already added the jitpack repositories in the project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

Comment: There are new versions, use them? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife

Comment: Under Gradle Scripts navigate to build.gradle(Module:app) and add the following line inside the dependencies tag.

Sync Gradle and try again

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'

Comment: The latest version at this moment is : 10.1.0
you can find all the version from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife-compiler

Comment: Why the Butter Knife website is not up to date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

Comment: Seems to work but the build doesn't work:
ause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)

Comment: try remove your support-compat and support-v4 from your dependencies and use this 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

Comment: I don't think I have support-v4 library

Comment: remove support-compat and replace it with 2 lines implementation in last comment

Comment: It seems to work like a charm! I don't understand why I have to replace these settings because it's the default settings... But anyway thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use This:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

from [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton/butterknife-compiler) `butterknife-compiler` version `7.0.1` not listed(founded) in mvn repository

so use the latest lib version

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
```

Comment: I have the following error now: 
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-26:19 to override.

Comment: that is androidx issue

Comment: @mamenejr so downgrade your version

Comment: @mamenejr try version  `8.7.0`

Answer (score 2):

If you are building an old android project and do not want to upgrade your butterknife dependency then add this to your gradle(app level) file. It wokred for me.  Happy Coding :)

```
android {
   ...
  defaultConfig {
    javaCompileOptions {
      annotationProcessorOptions {
        includeCompileClasspath = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```